# Help picking a transistor for and analysing a colpitts oscillator

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, oscillator, microprocessor, crystal

I am working on a development board for a digital synthesizer. I have set up a colpitts oscillator circuit for the oscillator that is needed by the microprocessor. I picked originally a [PMBS3904](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMBS3904.pdf) as the transistor for the oscillator, thinking it was the SMD equivalent of a 2N3904. I know that the 2N3904 works, and for now I have ended up soldering the through hole version onto the SMD pads just to get the board running while I figure this out. I have found that the MMBT3904 would essentially be the SMD equivalent, but I don't have immediate access to this because I am in the EU. Given that I have little knowledge about transistors and how to pick them, I am hoping for some help analysing this circuit and finding a suitable substitute transistor that I can hopefully find in an SMD package.
Two transistors that I do have immediate access to are [BC848](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000153262DS01/datenblatt-153262-infineon-technologies-transistor-bjt-diskret-bc848c-sot-23-3-anzahl-kanaele-1-npn.pdf) and [BC817](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000153076DS01/datenblatt-153076-infineon-technologies-transistor-bjt-diskret-bc817k-40e6327-sot-23-3-anzahl-kanaele-1-npn-tape-cut.pdf). I am also wondering if either of these would work as well and why.

## The schematic:

`PER33` is a stable 3.3v power supply
`XTAL_IN` is the node where the oscillator signal (25MHz sine wave) connects to the oscillator input on the microprocessor

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What microprocessor would need such complex circuit to operate? Usually there is no reason to build a discrete oscillator, so maybe you are doing something wrong? Usually MCUs either have a built-in oscillator so simply connect a crystal (with load caps and maybe few resistors) or then buy a clock oscillator module that outputs square wave to MCU.

Comment: Why not try it with a BC548 (leaded version of 848)?

Comment: So I tried a BC847 which worked, so that is good :) I still would like to know what I did wrong picking the first transistor though, as PMBS3904 and 2N3904 had very similar data sheets I thought. Apparently I missed some key characteristic though :/

Comment: PMBS3904 has **GBW** (gain-bandwidth-product) of 180 MHz compared with MMBT3904's 300 MHz.

Comment: Myself not knowing really what GBW is (I'll look into it now a bit to find out), I assumed that this difference wouldn't have much of an effect, given that the circuit is for a 25MHz signal. Would this characteristic still be something to consider?